# Print out a numpy array with the BMIs of all players whose BMI is below 21

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Use light inside square brackets to do a selection on the bmi array.

```
import numpy as np
```

###### Calculate the BMI: bmi

```
np_height_m = np.array(height_in) * 0.0254
np_weight_kg = np.array(weight_lb) * 0.453592
bmi = np_weight_kg / np_height_m ** 2
print(bmi)
```

###### Create the light array

```
light = bmi<21
```

###### Print out light

```
print(light)
```

###### Print out BMIs of all baseball players whose BMI is below 21

```
bmi[light<21]
```

Comment: i am trying  to print all element of bmi which value is less than 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`light` is an array of booleans. You should use it directly to slice:

```
bmi[light]
```

When you run:

```
bmi[light<21]  # equivalent to bmi[(bmi<21)<21]
```

This compares the booleans to 21, which is always `True` as `True` equals `1` and `False` equals `0`. This thus yields all elements.

Of note, you don't need the intermediate `light` array, you could use directly:

```
bmi[bmi<21]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
```

Calculate the BMI: bmi

```
np_height_m = np.array(height_in) * 0.0254
np_weight_kg = np.array(weight_lb) * 0.453592
bmi = np_weight_kg / np_height_m ** 2
print(bmi)
```

Create the light array

```
light = bmi<21
```

Print out light

```
print(light)
```

Print out BMIs of all baseball players whose BMI is below 21

```
bmi[light]
```